# Deploy node app with http-server and forever

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, daemon, httpserver

I want to use http-server and forever.js to deploy my app to remote ubuntu server. But forever.js requires path to JS file, not to executable. So I can't pass keys to http-server. Best solution so far is to install http-server locally via npm and run something like this: `forever start ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server`. But in this case I can't set port and other options. What's the best practice?

Answer (score 16):

You can set the options using that code. Just use the [available flags](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server#available-options) after the end of your command. For example:

```
forever start ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -p 80 -d false
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. Found a node.js [script](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs) that can run shell commands and used it to run the http-server command along with options.

example of node.js script named 'startserver.js':

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("sudo http-server -a ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 80", puts);
```

Then you can run it using forever:

```
forever start startserver.js
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$ forever start $(which http-server) -p 8000 -d false
```

you can add any parameters after `forever start $(which http-server)`

`$(which http-server)`: return the http-server path
`-p 8000` : port 8000, change it to any port number
`-d`: Show directory listings

Comment: this actually is a clever answer.

Comment: Hi I did this and it doesn't serve the html files on that path. doesn't open the ip in browser

forever start $(which http-server) -p 8001 -a 10.4.145.192 false

Comment: How do i point to the script with your command above?

Answer (score 4):

This worked with me

First get path of http-server like this

```
which http-server
```

for example you will get "/usr/bin/http-server"

then after that write the forever followed by http-server path and your app path

```
forever start /usr/bin/http-server /your/app/path
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Browse to your directory that contains your files
And from the command line type:
forever start -c http-server . -p your_port_number
Example:
forever start -c http-server -p 8000

In this way, the port 8000 will forever point to the html files in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me.

forever start npm\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server

Before this you should find your npm directory.