# Running http-server in background from an npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, background-process, httpserver

How do you start `http-server` in the background from an **npm** script so that another **npm** script, such as a [Mocha test using jsdom](https://github.com/dnajs/load-web-page-jsdom-mocha), can make an HTTP request to `http-server`?

The `http-server` package was installed with:

```
npm install http-server --save-dev
```

The `package.json` file contains:

```
"scripts": {
   "pretest": "gulp build-httpdocs",
   "test": "http-server -p 7777 httpdocs/ && mocha spec.js"
},
```

Running `npm test` successfully starts the `http-server`, but of course the command hangs after showing:

```
Starting up http-server, serving httpdocs/
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:7777
  http://192.168.1.64:7777
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Is there an easy way to start the web server so it does not block the Mocha tests?

*Bonus:* How do you shut down `http-server` after the Mocha tests have run?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456618/deploy-node-app-with-http-server-and-forever

Comment: @IleshPatel That question does not have an accepted answer and it does not apply to npm scripts.

Comment: are you on linux/mac or on windows?

Comment: It would be nice to work on both, but I really only need linux/mac.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can run a process in background by appending `&` in the end.
And then use the `postscript` hook that npm offers us, in order to kill the background process.

```
"scripts": {
    "web-server": "http-server -p 7777 httpdocs &",
    "pretest": "gulp build-httpdocs && npm run web-server",
    "test": "mocha spec.js",
    "posttest": "pkill -f http-server"
}
```

**But what if I have multiple `http-server` running?**

You can kill a process by specifying its port in the `posttest` script:

```
    "posttest": "kill $(lsof -t -i:7777)"
```

Now for Windows, syntax is different and as far as I know npm doesn't support multiple OS scripts. For supporting multiple my best bet would be a gulp task that will handle each OS different.

Comment: This answer got me there, but I had to make two tweaks (at least for *macOS*): **1)** The `http-server` command needs to be its own separate npm script because the trailing `&` must be at the very end AND it causes everything on the line to be run in background and **2)** The `-f` flag is needed to shutdown the web server (`"pkill -f http-server"`)

Comment: I am glad you got it working! I didn't have linux/mac to test it so I wrote it from memory! Please if you found the solution edit mine or create a new to close it.

Comment: Does not work on Win7. It does not put the process in the background. I am trying it with express.

Comment: The `&` is not a cross platform solution, which is limits the portability of npm-scripts

Answer (score 4):

Probably the cross platform problem can be solved by [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all#%EF%B8%8F-motivation)

Comment: Yes! `run-p --race runHttpServer runTest`